# Chipmunk/spacemanager

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I have been working on a project for a few months now and decided to update to cocos2d 1.0.0 and now my program keeps crashing on this method

```
[smgr morphShapeToActive:self.currentFootball.shape mass:25];
```

I was told by a friend that this method has been deprecated in the newer chipmunk builds. Is that true and if so how would I go about doing this method if it no longer exists. Also does anyone now where I can find out which methods are deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with SpaceManager, but that function almost certainly adds and removes shapes. Are you calling it from within a callback? You can't do that, and it may or may not have an assertion to make sure that you don't.

As far as checking if it's deprecated, what does it say in the header?